# React-chartjs-2 gradient fill error on canvas context

Tags: reactjs, canvas, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I have a react-chart-js2 component that I am trying to make a gradient on the fill however I am getting a few different typescript errors and cant seem to get it working.

The documentation says to pass the data prop as a function with a reference to the canvas in order to access the canvas context to add the gradient. Unfortunately this is not working.

Here is a codesandbox of the files: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-bird-j2in8 (file LineChartGradient.tsx)

The errors I get surround the Canvas Context and passing a data function to the chartjs  component

**Data**

```
const data = (canvas: HTMLCanvasElement) => {
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 200);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(250,174,50,1)");
    gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(250,174,50,0)");

    return {
      labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "First dataset",
          data: [33, 53, 85, 41, 44, 65],
          fill: "start",
          backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.2)",
          borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)"
        },
        {
          label: "Second dataset",
          data: [33, 25, 35, 51, 54, 76],
          fill: "start",
          borderColor: "#742774"
        }
      ]
    };
  };
```

**Component**

```
  return (
    <div>
      <Line data={data} options={options} />
    </div>
  );
```

Error #1

```
const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 200);
```

*Typescript saying that this object could possible be null*, this is fine I can check if it exists but it is my first clue that the canvas element is not being passed

Error #2

```
<Line data={data} options={options} />
```

*Property 'datasets' is missing in type '(canvas: HTMLCanvasElement) => { labels: string[]; datasets:*

When passing the data as a function I get this error however if I just drop the object that is returned by the data function inside the data prop the graph renders fine (See LineChart.tsx).

What is the correct way of accessing the canvas context in react-chartjs-2 to add a gradient fill?

Answer (score 18):

This is because you dont pass any canvas to the data function when you call it in

```html
<Line data={data} options={options} />
```

But the canvas is also not availabale here. If you want to make a custom gradient you will need to apply a scriptable option for the `backgroundColor` like so:

```js
const data = () => {
  return {
    labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "First dataset",
      data: [33, 53, 85, 41, 44, 65],
      fill: "start",
      backgroundColor: (context: ScriptableContext<"line">) => {
        const ctx = context.chart.ctx;
        const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 200);
        gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(250,174,50,1)");
        gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(250,174,50,0)");
        return gradient;
      },
      borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)"
    }]
  };
};
```

Also make sure to call the function in your data field so your html becomes this:

```html
<Line data={data()} options={options} />
```

Working Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-faraday-204ugi?file=/src/LineChartGradient.tsx

Answer (score -1):

so it's look that there is a lot of errors with your code , i'm trying to help by solving the second problem , `data` should be json not a function so to solve this you should to execute the function before pass it like this :

```js
<Line data={data()} options={options} />
```

```js
  
  export default function Chart(){
    return (
    <div>
    {
    /****
    pass data() not data
    ****/
    }
      <Line data={data()} options={options} />
    </div>
  );
  }
```

Comment: ive tried this before this isnt it, this also fires off the data function immediately instead of passing it as a prop where it should then be passed context from chartjs lib

Comment: you tried execute it outside and assign it to a variable then pass it ?

Comment: This is not correct. Data also accepts a function that importantly has the html canvas element as the first parameter, making things like what OP is asking about significantly easier.